# How to ensure priveleges go to the right users

Tags: discussion

On our site, privileges are awarded based on reputation, and reputation is awarded (primarily) based on participation. Let me reiterate: Privileges are not necessarily tied to post **quality**; they are tied to how much **time** you spend on the site.

The problem arises when we encounter a user who is either (A) not able to consistently provide a well-written post, or (B) not able to consistently provide answers that accurately represent Christianity. These users will experience some embarrassment as their posts are down-voted and/or deleted, but in general, over time, they will continue to earn reputation **and privileges**.

I recently suggested ([in another post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615/1548)) that we adjust the reputation cost and effect of a down-vote as a potential remedy. Caleb has convinced me that I may have been going after the wrong solution. However, fredsbend convinced me that the problem is real, so I thought I would post the problem in a separate question and let the community answer it.

**How can we ensure that site privileges go to the right users?**

Answer (score 9):

To be perfectly honest, the only ways we can do this are the following:

1. Make sure you upvote good content and downvote bad content.
2. Make sure you are conscientious about who you vote for as moderator.

Here's the deal. We have really low priv level right now, anyone with half a brain can get a few thousand rep and basically have all the reputation of a 10k member on SO or any other graduated site (heck, I even managed to).

When our design is finished those priv levels shoot up, basically by an order of magnitude. They become far less achievable. Close votes start at 3k, deletes at 10k and 20k.

No one will claim that reputation based privileges is the best way to give them out, but right now it's the only way, and for the most part it works pretty well. You have to stick around and know the site for a bit before you can do things. Obviously that sometimes leads to long term members who still dont 'get it', but SO has that problem too. This is just part of the thing we live with in this system.

What folks have to be educated on is that a high reputation does not mean someone is an expert, it mostly just means that they have too much time on their hands.

Last thing, if you see someone continuously posting garbage, but still gaining rep for it, let a mod know via a flag. One of our templates for moderator messages is low quality contributions over time, if you see a consistent pattern that we seem to be missing, let us know and we will investigate.

Comment: "[Having lots of rep] mostly just means that they have too much time on their hands." Sounds about right. lol.

Comment: Hey, I resemble that remark!

Answer (score -6):

One idea I had was to add a -100 rep. penalty for questions and answers that are deleted.

Comment: a 100 rep penalty is assessed when a post is marked offensive or spam. It's not something we want to be awarding for any other reason.

Comment: @waxeagle Interesting. (I did not know that.) Anyway, it was just a random idea. I'm looking forward to better answers!

Comment: This would backfire and have the opposite effect from what you are trying to achieve. In order to keep a clean house, we want the cleanup process to be as low friction as possible. This would turn into a deterrent against deletion and would cause widespread consternation and conflict. You'd be surprised how much flack we get when 100 points are docked for hate speech and outright spam. We don't want normal housecleaning to kick up huge amounts of dust.